# How to select all values by default in JIRA multiselect properties?

Tags: xml, jira, jira-plugin

How to select all values by default in JIRA multiselect properties?
This is my XML sample.

```
<property>
    <key>groupType</key>
    <name>Group Type</name>
    <description>Group Type</description>
    <type>multiselect</type>
    <values>
        <value>
            <key>test1</key>
            <value>test1value</value>
        </value>
        <value>
            <key>regionCourse</key>
            <value>Курс в регионах</value>
        </value>
    </values>
</property>
```

Comment: In customfield configuration you can specify default values.

Comment: @Pavol Celuch Can you explain in more detailed way?

Comment: What I understood from your description, you are trying to have default value selected when creating issue. If you go to Administration -> Issues -> Custom fields -> Your field configuration , you can find there option to edit Default Values.